# How to import Java in a javascript program

Tags: java, reactjs

I want to use a java program which I have already written on a web page which I am programming in React.

I have seen online I should use Java.type("[class name]") but I cannot get Java to import in my React program.

```
import Java from "JSON";

var className = Java.type("javaFiles.className");
```

I know that importing from "JSON" doesn't work, but I don't know where to import from.

Comment: `Java.type` is nashorn syntax; Nashorn is the JavaScript engine built into Java. There is no Java implementation built into JavaScript. At one time you could have used applets, but they are no longer functional. In short, you probably can't do what you're trying to do the way you're trying to do it and you will need to decide on a new architecture.

Answer (score 1):

The sad truth is that you simply can't.